# Существует ли законный способ преобразовать const_iterator в iterator?

Tags: c++, итераторы, cast

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли законно преобразовать `const_iterator` в `iterator`?

Проблема следующая:

Я пишу индексатор, в публичном интерфейсе которого фигурирует хэндл, который имеет тип `std::list<...>::const_iterator`. Это сделано для того, чтобы внешний код мог самостоятельно использовать данный итератор для вызова константных методов (геттеров) того, на что указывает итератор данного типа.

Например:

```
class Object
{
    // ...
    public:
    size_t GetField() const
    {
        return field;
    }

    private:
    size_t key;
    size_t field;
};

class Indexator
{
    public:
    using Handle = std::list<Object>::const_iterator;

    Handle GetObjectByKey(const size_t key) const
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Но я также хочу, чтобы внешний код смог поменять неиндексируемые поля, пускай и через использование методов `Indexer`.

Например так:

```
void Indexator::SetField(Handle handle)
{
    std::list<Object>::iterator iterator = (cast?) handle;
    iterator->field = ...;
}
```

Существует ли законный способ преобразовать `const_iterator` в `iterator`?

Comment: необходимость преобразовывать конст в неконст - первый признак, что делаешь что-то неправильно и есть способ сделать это другим, лучшим способом

Comment: @asianirish, я понимаю, что можно сделать пару оберток над `iterator`, это решит все проблемы. Но мне интересно, возможно ли в принципе преобразовать `const_iterator` в `iterator`?

Comment: `mutable` какой-нибудь

Comment: Нет, а почему это должно быть возможно? Это эквивалентно переделыванию указателя на объект с const квалификатором в указатель на объект без квалификаторов. Логично, что посредством const_iterator у пользователя не должно быть возможности менять объект, на который тот ссылается. Можно конечно пробежаться по std::list<Object> до нужного объекта.

Comment: @user7860670, то, что вы привели в пример, возможно, если изначальный объект не является константным.

Comment: По  неконстантному итератору тоже можно вызвать константные методы,  не нужно усложнять все

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, по неконстантному итератору можно вызвать и неконстантные методы, сломав инвариант класса и перепутав всю логику.

Comment: @MGNeo, если вызвав неконстантные методы ломается инвариант, прочитайте первый комментарий от `asianirish `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример законного (но неэффективного) способа:

```
::std::list<Object> items{};
...
::std::list<Object>::iterator p_non_const
{
    ::std::find_if
    (
        items.begin()
    ,   items.end()
    ,   [handle](Object const & object) noexcept -> bool
        {
            return ::std::addressof(object) == ::std::addressof(*handle);
        }
    )
};
```

Comment: Законен ли такой способ: `Object& object = const_cast<Object&>(*handle)`?

Comment: @MGNeo Не исключено...